# Win7_64bit UEFI GPT installation stucked at the very beginning

Tags: windows-7, installation, multi-boot

I'm installing **Win7 64bit Pro** on a Win8.1->Win10 PC to make a dual boot.

I've got a clean partition in **GPT, NTFS formatted** to install Win7.

I've downloaded the ISO from Microsoft servers and burned on a DVD.

I'm working in UEFI mode, security booth disabled (in order to run the DVD boot).

My machine is a
Lenovo IdeaPad Z510
Intel Core i7 4702MQ2.2GHz quadcore
8Gb RAM
...and other things...

DVD inside, I turn on the pc, "press any key to boot from DVD" it reads from the DVD and the lower loading bar goes to 100% in a matter of seconds, than comes the tipical "Windows Starting" screen (black background) but no progression bar (you know, the tipical green one that goes and goes just to show you it's alive); nor DVD or fan activity, nothing, it's just turned on.

I've red that sometimes a USB drive or other periferals may cause some conflict but this time nothing is pluged in (but the power supply of course).

I've waited for 10-15mins before to shut it down and retry, but nothing has changed.
It's exactly like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkY7Zu9B6JY

but I can't use the Legacy mode because the HDD is in GPT (not MBR as it expects). Legacy is quite outdated and Win7_64bit should run in UEFI too.

What can I check? Do I have to wait that long? Is itnormal? It's frustrating that it takes that long to show any form of activity and I can remember the green bar that says "hey, I'm here, I'm working, be patient" but this time this buddy was not there.

Suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Usb3 or usb2 ports?

Comment: I'm using a DVD, nothing is pluged.
Because I'm stucked I'm trying to use a USB bootable drive.

I'm following this tutorial (very well done, documented and explained)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IxUprqB2PM

but he format the USB drive in fat32; than copying the content of the ISO file the filesystem can't handle the install.wim because is larger than 4Gb (4.6Gb). No one has reported this issue.

Is this size correct?
What if I use ntfs instead?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  USB3 or USB2.  If you do not provide that information I literally cannot help.  Use Rufus to make the USB bootable drive instead of following that invalid tutorial.

Comment: I've got USB3 port on the laptop (but also an USB2).

I would rectify some baloney I've said:
"No one has reported this issue"...it's just hilarious!
"What if I use ntfs instead?" ...it just doesn't work for UEFI installation.

I've one doubt: Rufus has 3 options for Partition scheme and target system type: MBR for BIOS or UEFI, MBR for UEFI and GPT for UEFI.
Where should I check for my partition scheme?

Comment: Use the GPT/UEFI option, obviously. And you actually need a USB stick to install Windows 7 in UEFI mode. The DVD does not support it.